# Unable to remove element on click

Tags: jquery

I have a page where I appendTo a div on page load. After a user can dismiss this div by clicking another element.

```
var overlay = jQuery('<div id="start">111111111</div>');
overlay.appendTo(document.body);

$("#go").click(function() {
    $(document).remove("#start");
});
```

Unfortunately it does append the div, but not remove... What am iI missing?

Answer (score 2):

How about finding the element first, then calling remove on it instead:

```
$('#start').remove();
```

Also, this could be changed a bit:

```
$('<div>',{'id':'start'}).text('111111111').appendTo('body');

$('#go').on('click',function(e){
  $('#start').remove();
});
```

Unless you're using an antiquated version of jQuery, [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) should be used for binding instead (see documentation).

And if you wanted to store it as `overlay`, you may as well use it (re-reference it):

```
var overlay = $('<div>',{'id':'start'}).text('111111111').appendTo('body');
$('#go').on('click',function(e){
  overlay.remove();
});
```

[Example of above](http://jsfiddle.net/Ac4Bb/)

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/7y6bY/

API : http://api.jquery.com/remove/

**Code**

```
var overlay = jQuery('<div id="start">111111111</div>');
overlay.appendTo(document.body);

$("#go").click(function() {
    $("#start").remove();
});​
```